# show pdf file in android studio using java, from a google drive link?

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-viewer

i m trying to show a pdf file from my google drive link sush as
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H7GwpxteH-w3rSaQzd91sc15xNW5lFbG/view?usp=sharing
in android studio using the android-pdf-viewer. but this dependency works only with an uri with .pdf in the end. any way to solve this problem??;(

Comment: Download the PDF (e.g., using OkHttp). Then, show the downloaded PDF.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah i tried that one, and really i was shocked when i generated the final apk. from 6Mo before implementing the library to 47Mo after, it was so crazy for just a pdf reader app ;(

Answer (score 0):

when i was using the android-pdf-viewer package i faced 2 problems: cant display a pdf from an url and the huge size of the generated apk.
i searched a lot for a good alternative but nothing found.
thats why i dispayed my pdfs in a webview. so it was fine.
One last problem was the long time to upload and display a google drive link in the webview. ;(